# Resolve remote host names into ip addresses in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I'm interested in the ip address of remote hosts. Is there an easy way to resolve a host name into its ip address?

After searching in the codename one source code and reading through the documentation, the only way to achieve this seems by implement android/ios native features (e.g. using the `InetAddress` class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you would need to implement this using native code or thru the Socket API by implementing the DNS protocol calls.

The `InetAddress` class can be used in the Android/Desktop ports but other platforms (e.g. iOS) would need the Objective-C/C equivalent of that.

Comment: Thank you Shai for confirmation.